# Inserting datetime in sqlite database android

Tags: android, sqlite

how can i insert datetime data in my sqlite database using contentvalues not using raw query?.

datetime('now') insert itself(text) not the time, and can i add addittional hours to the current time?

like, when i press button "1HOUR" it would insert the currenttime + 1 hour in the sqlite database..thanks, kinda confused..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert date/time to milliseconds and you get a `long`. Then you just insert the `long` value in database.

You can add date/time values together if they are in milliseconds.

--EDITED--

```
    Date myDate = new Date();
    long timeMilliseconds = myDate.getTime();
    //add 1 hour
    timeMilliseconds = timeMilliseconds + 3600 * 1000; //3600 seconds * 1000 milliseconds
    //To convert back to Date
    Date myDateNew = new Date(timeMilliseconds);
```

In SQLite the java `long` value is stored as a `int`.

Comment: can you show me the syntax, im really clueless.. how can i convert it?

Comment: Thanks!!!, this is what i need..  when i insert it via long, everything, i can retrieve and convert it the way i want, but when i insert it via a formatted(YYYY-DD-MM) i cant retrieve it, if i retrieve it via long it only retrive the year, and if via getString, its only a string, i can't convert it to actual milli, is there a work around? i can use the long method, but it would be more convenient in my database if it is a readable one..thanks..really helped me

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the datetime functions using the Java wrapper "ContentValues". You can implement in this ways :

1) You can useSQLiteDatabase.execSQL (raw SQL query)

```
 dbObj.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+DATABASE_TABLE+" VALUES (null, datetime()) ");
```

2) You can use SimpleDateFormat

```
// setting the format to sql date time
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
Date date = new Date();
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues(); 
initialValues.put("date_time", dateFormat.format(date));
long recordId = mDb.insert(DB_TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);
```

3)  you store date value in database as (long type) milliseconds and for displaying you can format it,

```
 import java.text.DateFormat;
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.Calendar;

System.out.println(getDate(82233213123L, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS"));

// Return date in specified format.
// milliSeconds Date in milliseconds
// dateFormat Date format 
// return date as string in specified format

public static String formatDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)
{

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

// Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date. 
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
 return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
   }
 }
```

1 Second = 1000 Milliseconds, so if you want to add 1 hour then use this formula

```
  currentTImeMilli + (60 * 60 * 1000)
```

Comment: i used the second one, but using system.currentmills, then formatting it.. thanks. it works, now i got a new question, if i retrieve the date, "2012-10-28 09:58:15" how can i convert it to the format that system.currentmillis use? i need that because my application need to compare the current time to a certain time( in this case, +1hour)