# Android: insert datetime in Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert datetime field in Sqlite database in an Andoird project. Tried many ways [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105609/inserting-datetime-in-sqlite-database-android) but no luck in inserting datetime field.  Here are facts

1] My Sqlite field is type timestamp

2] database class

```
package com.gcm.pushandroid;
import java.util.Date;

public class Notifications {

     //private variables 
      String _type; 
      String _time_stamp;


       // Empty constructor 
       public Notifications(){ 

       } 
       // constructor 
       public Notifications(String type, String timeStamp){ 
           this._type = type; 
           this._time_stamp = timeStamp;
       } 


      // getting ID 
      public String getType(){ 
          return this._type; 
       } 

      // setting id 
      public void setType(String type){ 
         this._type = type; 
      } 

     // getting timestamp
     public String getTimeStamp(){ 
        return this._time_stamp; 
     } 

     // setting 
     public void setTimeStamp(String time_stamp){ 
          this._time_stamp = time_stamp; 
     } 

}
```

3] Here is code

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
values.put(KEY_TYPE, notificationObj.getType());  
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
Date date = new Date();
values.put("time_stamp", dateFormat.format(date));
db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values); 
db.close();
```

Don't know what is going wrong. Help is apprecited.
Thank you

Comment: We don't know what is going wrong either. You said "no luck inserting" it... what does that mean?

Comment: "No luck" doesn't describe the misbehavior you're trying to correct. For what it's worth, SQLite doesn't have a date/time column type; see http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. You have to decide what format best represents dates and times and do the conversion yourself. You don't necessarily have to write conversion code, as there are date/time conversion functions in SQLite, but you have to decide whether to represent date/time info as a string, integer-style UNIX time, or what have you. You'll get more help if you describe what you saw that you didn't like.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your sqlite field type to String / Text. 
The type 'timestamp' doesn't allow : or - Timestamp may only hold Integers

For more details please see http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html Point 1.2